# Live release of React Native app crashes with : TypeError: null is not an object 'h.NativeAppearance.initialPreferences'

Tags: android, react-native

I recently released my app on the playstore and the release build crashes with the following error. The crazy part is that the debug build works just fine so there is no way to debug.

````
com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'h.NativeAppearance.initialPreferences'), stack: hermes, stack:
anonymous@607:1375
h@2:1585
d@2:1028
o@2:496
anonymous@436:184
h@2:1585
d@2:1028
o@2:496
anonymous@435:197
h@2:1585
d@2:1028
o@2:496
anonymous@434:136
h@2:1585
d@2:1028
o@2:496
anonymous@6:69
h@2:1585
d@2:958
o@2:496
global@2412:3
  at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException (ExceptionsManagerModule.java:83)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke (JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke (JavaModuleWrapper.java:188)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:942)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage (MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:201)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:288)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run (MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1012)```
````